# WD 500gb harddrive does not show up on pc

Tags: external-hard-drive

I was transfering files to my external hard drive when it stalled during the transfer.  I unplugged the hard drive.  Now when i connect it, the light on the hard drive comes on and flashes.  You can hear/feel the hard drive running.  On the pc when i go to "my computer" it no longer shows the hard drive.  Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maxtor 500GB external hard drive not being detected but power is going to it?](http://superuser.com/questions/305832/maxtor-500gb-external-hard-drive-not-being-detected-but-power-is-going-to-it), [External hard drive is not being recognized by computer](http://superuser.com/questions/459485/external-hard-drive-is-not-being-recognized-by-computer), etc.

Answer (score 1):

As per your description that you can hear and feel it spinning up, in addition to the lights looking healthy, I'm inclined to conclude that your harddrive is mechanically fine.

Without any diagnostics of the initiall stall I cannot say what caused that, but it could be one of many things, some severe, but most of them harmless.

The issue you're now facing is most likely due to filesystem corruption: The disk was being written to when it was unplugged. Effects of this can be many, these too ranging from minor ones solvable by a filesystem check, or more severe ones such as corruption of the partition table and/or the filesystem in general.

What should be done now is to verify that the drive does register as such by looking at the hardware in the control panel. Once that is done, see if you can delete any partitions on it and repartition it.

Comment: That does sound optimistic. I was transferring a TV series file MP4 when it stalled. How would I verify if it registers?  When I plug the hard drive in to the pc it does not show in "my computer"